# Using unique constraints with Grails Datasources plugin causes NullPointerException

Tags: grails, plugins, groovy, datasource, unique-constraint

I am using the Datasources grails plugin (version 0.5), so that I can use multiple databases with my application. However I am running into a problem with unique constraints, even if they are defined in the original DataSource.groovy (not Datasources.groovy). Any unique constraint, such as:

```
static constraints = {
        username(blank: false, unique: true, minSize: 4, maxSize: 255)
}
```

results in an error such as:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot get property 'com.giivpro.domain.users.MerchantUser' on null object
   at com.burtbeckwith.grails.plugin.datasources.DatasourcesUniqueConstraintFactory$_build_closure1.doCall(DatasourcesUniqueConstraintFactory.groovy:31)
```

It looks like (from what I've read on various forums) that the author has fixed this in the 0.5 version, but I am not seeing evidence of this in my application. Has anyone else had this issue, and is there a known workaround?

Answer (score 1):

The benefits of the datasources plugin are built in to grails 2+.  It looks like unique constraints are supported, perhaps that will work for you?

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like http://jira.grails.org/browse/GPDATASOURCES-16 which includes a work-around.  It is written on 0.5 and still open.  I wonder if configuring some Datasources would avoid it.